# How shopify_api work with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, shopify

I am designing a shopify app which enables customers buying product through mobile phones. The scenario is customers need to be able to sign up with omniauth and then they can get the products info from the app. However, before any customer can get products info from a shop, my shopify app should first authenticate with the shop owner using omniauth.

The problem now is devise will modify omniauth default authenticate strategy. If I use shopify_api, I auth through path auth/shopify, it can work without devise installed. If devise is installed, it will redirect auth/shopify to omniauth/shopify. I find this path is generated by devise. How can I skip devise and use the original omniauth path? Thanks.

Comment: Code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Devsie has [a good tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth-with-multiple-models) on how to separate `omniauthable` out of your devise model. This will allow you to configure your own omniauth settings.

Once you've set-up a provider for both providers in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` and removed `devise.omniauth` from `conifg/initializers/devise.rb`, you'll need to set-up your routes to handle the response from OAuth differently.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/auth/:action/callback", to: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', constraints: { action: /facebook/ }
end

get 'auth/:action/callback' => 'another_controller', constraints: { action: /shopify/ } # connections
```

Then in **another_controller.rb**

```
class AnotherController
  def shopify
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

    shop = auth_hash[:uid]
    token = auth_hash[:credentials][:token]

    ShopifyAPI::Session.temp("#{shop}.myshopify.com", token) do
      current_shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.